# SQL BulkCopy doesn't insert into database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, bulkinsert

Most of my application is using LinqToSQL, but I need to do some uploading from file and thus inserting large quantities of Data.

Here I've got a list of the data, and I'm trying to insert it. I convert to table (leaving out the identity MeterDataId field from the column mappings). Everything seems to work fine, but the data doesn't get submitted. There are no exceptions reported.

I checked the table, and it does have data for the three fields.

Should I be setting the ID field somehow?

Thanks

```
        SqlConnection SqlConnection = null;
        try {
            string cons = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=\"D:\\Visual Studio Projects\\SEMS\\SEMS\\bin\\Debug\\DataCore.mdf\";Integrated Security=True";

            SqlConnection = new SqlConnection(cons);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }

        Type t = typeof(MeterData);

        var tableAttribute = (TableAttribute)t.GetCustomAttributes(
            typeof(TableAttribute), false).Single();

        var bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(SqlConnection) {
            DestinationTableName = tableAttribute.Name
        };

        List<PropertyInfo> properties = new List<PropertyInfo>();

        properties.Add(t.GetProperty("DateTime"));
        properties.Add(t.GetProperty("Value"));
        properties.Add(t.GetProperty("Difference"));

        var table = new DataTable();

        foreach (var property in properties) {
            Type propertyType = property.PropertyType;
            if (propertyType.IsGenericType &&
                propertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>)) {
                propertyType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(propertyType);
            }

            // set the SqlBulkCopy column mappings.
            table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(property.Name, propertyType));
            var clrPropertyName = property.Name;
            var tableColumnName = property.Name;
            bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(new SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping(clrPropertyName, tableColumnName));
        }

        // Add all our entities to our data table
        foreach (var entity in insertMeterDatas) {
            var e = entity;
            table.Rows.Add(properties.Select(property => GetPropertyValue(property.GetValue(e, null))).ToArray());
        }

        bulkCopy.WriteToServer(table);

        SqlConnection.Close();
```

Comment: you should open the sql connection with `using` then, you don't need to clean up the connection. It will be done automatically. Also, if something fails, the connection will not be closed properly the way your code is written right now. Look into it, `using` is great!

Answer (score 0):

```
   string cs = DataContext.Connection.ConnectionString;
```

Updated the connection string, seems to be working now!

**Edit** That wasn't the trick. I found disposing of the Linq DataContext it worked, but that messed up everything else.

Solution: use the DataContext.Connection (Cast to SQLConnection) with the BulkInsert. Then it uses the already open sql connection, seems to be working fine now.